# Objeto não pode ser convertido em dbnull em outros tipos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-4

Boa tarde senhores.

Estou fazendo um cadastro de usuário no trabalho da faculdade e ao logar aparece este erro.

Como posso resolver?

[image: <code>ERRO</code>]

```
    private Usuario Mapear(DataRow registro)
    {
        var usuario = new Usuario();

        usuario.Nome = Convert.ToString(registro["NOME"]);
        usuario.Senha = Convert.ToString(registro["SENHA"]);
        usuario.Email = Convert.ToString(registro["EMAIL"]);
        usuario.Telefone = Convert.ToString(registro["TELEFONE"]);
        usuario.Status = (Status)Convert.ToInt32(registro["STATUS"]);
        //usuario.Funcao = Convert.ToString(registro["FUNCAO"]);
        //usuario.Setor = Convert.ToString(registro["SETOR"]);

        return usuario;
    }
```

---

Não sei como proceder.
Já tentei quase tudo.

[image: Erro]

Comment: Qual valor esse campo `registro["STATUS"]` retorna?

Comment: Não use caixa-alta, jovem. é feio, kkkkk

Comment: Provavelmente o dado ( registro["STATUS"]) esta retornando um valor nulo, sendo assim não é possível converter para int. Só para confirmar, antes de converter exiba oque está sendo trazido, para podermos verificar

Comment: Use um ORM, não perca tempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O campo em questão está retornando DbNull e você tenta convertê-lo para inteiro.

Faça verificações antes de uma conversão:

```
public static  Usuario Mapear(DataRow registro)
{
    var usuario = new Usuario();
    usuario.Nome = Convert.ToString(registro["NOME"]);

    if (registro["STATUS"] != DBNull.Value)
        usuario.Status = (Status)Convert.ToInt32(registro["STATUS"]);
    else 
        usuario.Status = Status.status2; //se vier null, faça algo

    return usuario;
}
```

[**Exemplo no .NETFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pGUQd5)